# Detect file newline mode / reopen a file object

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, newline

I have a method that receives a text file object as input and extracts data using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

```py
def extract_data(csvfile):
    csv_data = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel-tab')
    # do things...
```

For `csv` to work correctly, `csvfile` must be a file object opened with `newline=''`. However, there seems to be no mechanism to check this.

[PEP 278](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/) describes the `newlines` attribute on file objects. However, this attribute seems to store the history of newline characters read/written so far, NOT the `newline` parameter.

Questions:

1. How can I detect that `csvfile` was opened using `newline=''`?
2. If 1. is impossible, how can I re-open `csvfile` myself? Does it also work with [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO), or with [`TemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile)?

Comment: You can re-open the file with `open(csvfile.name, newline='')`.

Comment: Interesting question and there doesn't seem to be any way to detect that. A non-optimal workaround would be to clone the file object first, and read every line to check if there are any `\r` characters. It might even be sufficient to read only the first line in some cases, although there is no guarantee that the file doesn't use mixed line endings.

Comment: @Ben Unfortunately, this would not work with `io.StringIO` or `TemporaryFile`.